# when i click the heart font that total item can be insert into databse

Tags: php, mysql

in my website some products are there.it had heart symbol for wishlist.my question is when I click the heart font the total data goes into wishlist.php page. I am using PHP and MySQL database to write code. Its working but id shown in URL when I refresh the page id is missing in URL and product data also missing in the wishlist page

I am using the new version of PHP with MySQL database.

```
<a href="couple-wishlist.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" class=""><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
                            $id=$_GET['id'];
                            $ins="insert into wishlist(sno,image,price,title,address) select id,image,price,title,address from vendorlist where id=$id";
                            $que=mysqli_query($connection,$ins);
                            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($que);
```

in the code, I gave id to the heart font of the anchor tag. When I click the heart the data goes into database wishlist table.output also came but I refresh the page in the URL id is missing and immediately product data is missing too.

Comment: Where do you set the ID?

Comment: it is coming from database and it is in while loop.

Comment: Could you add a snippet of that code too?

Comment: <?php

$sel="select * from vendorlist where categorytype='Banquet halls'";
$query=mysqli_query($connection,$sel);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$id=$row['id'];
$image=$row['image'];
$title=$row['title'];
$add=$row['address'];
$price=$row['price'];
?>

Comment: iam taking id from vendorlist table

Comment: please help my code